# Should extension methods handle null?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Is this bad practice (the returning `null` part)?

```
public static ObservableCollection<TSource> ToObservableCollection<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null) return null;
    return new ObservableCollection<TSource>(source);
}
```

Comment: If you used a method on null, SHOULDN'T it throw a NullRefException, instead of hiding it like you do? Edit: Or at least SOME exception.

Comment: Not always. `String.IsNullOrEmpty` would be a good example.

Comment: `NullReferenceException` is reserved to the CLR and should not be thrown by user code. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182338.aspx

Comment: @martin_costello just removing the check would ensure it was thrown, no need to throw it yourself (or you can throw `ArgumentNullException`).

Comment: @Blorgbeard No it wouldn't. It's being passed to a constructor and no members of it are accessed, so there's no null reference to invoke a member against.

Comment: @martin_costello ah yes true. In this case, ObservableCollection would throw `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: There are cases where I've used the fact that extension methods don't crash on null to deal with optional objects such as loggers. Even then, I named it TryLog. Even that kind of use is somewhat debatable, though. While my syntax highlighting displays extension methods in another color, others may not realize that nulls are valid for extension methods, causing general confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should throw an `ArgumentNullExcception`.  Most of the .NET Framework extension methods do this.  Alternatively, do nothing and let the `ObservableCollection<T>` constructor do it.

```
public static ObservableCollection<TSource> ToObservableCollection<TSource>(this     IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }

    return new ObservableCollection<TSource>(source);
}
```

Comment: This is probably better than letting the exception happen deeper, because this way they get the correct parameter name, and don't have to wonder if something else is wrong in a class they have no access to. The earlier the better for this sort of thing.

Comment: Good point about the parameter name matching.

Answer (score 0):

I write mine to handle null parameters, so I advocate null checks.  Extension methods are emitted differently in IL code. They emitted as a static method of a class thereby the parameters can be null.

UPDATE: either throw an exception or handle the null value appropriately is how I deal with null values in my extension methods.